# Button onClick get wrong position in viewholder patterned listview

Tags: android

I have a button inside the row of the listview. I want to detect its onClick event and position on the row (which row is clicked).

My current code is working, but it fires on the wrong row. So for example, if i click on the first row, the last row will be fired instead.

This is my getView :

```
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_cart, parent, false);

        holder = new CartHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CartHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.btnCartAddQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //WRONG POSITION
            getItem(position).setQty((Integer.parseInt(getItem(position).getQty())+1)+"");
            holder.txtCartQty.setText(getItem(position).getQty());
        }
    });
```

Where did i do wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

After doing some debug, it seems the position is detected correctly but the target of `setText` is wrong

So the culprit is in this line of code :

```
holder.txtCartQty.setText(getItem(position).getQty());
```

The code always target the last row item of `holder.txtCartQty`

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: why this is like final int position this

Comment: Are you returning object into getItem(int i)??

Comment: Yes it returns an object

Comment: Try Toast the position after clicked. Is the value correct?

Comment: @ZarulIzham Yeah thanks for your suggestion, just did some log and found out the culprit is not the position variable

Comment: Glad it helps :) @BlazeTama

Answer (score 2):

**Declare**

```
 LayoutInflater mInflater;  //Global
```

**Call this**

```
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); //Contractor
```

**Then**

```
 if (convertView == null)
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cart, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is there any difference with my current code?

Comment: I need to research what inflate(R.layout.item_cart, null); did, but doing so messed up my row item layout...

Comment: @BlazeTama Same problem happening ?

Comment: Please kindly see my updated question, the culprit is not the position but the holder instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`

So I get rid of this code :

```
holder.txtCartQty.setText(getItem(position).getQty());
```

and called `notifyDataSetChanged` instead

My mistake is i tried to update the holder manually and forgot one of the most basic principle of Android adapter

Thanks all for the help

Comment: sloppy mistake . `notifyDataSetChanged ` refresh